# Rails 3.2: Trouble changing root to a nested users resources index using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So I have Devise setup for a User class, and each user `has_many :items`. I'm trying to change the root for a signed in user to the index page for their items.

Here's my routes.rb file:

```
RequestApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :users do
    resources :items
  end

  authenticated :user do
    root :to =>  'users/:user_id/items#index'
  end

  devise_scope :user do
    root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
```

and then running rake routes gets me:

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)            devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)           devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                  registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                         registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                 registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                    registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                         registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                         registrations#destroy
              user_items GET    /users/:user_id/items(.:format)          items#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/items(.:format)          items#create
           new_user_item GET    /users/:user_id/items/new(.:format)      items#new
          edit_user_item GET    /users/:user_id/items/:id/edit(.:format) items#edit
               user_item GET    /users/:user_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#show
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                         users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                         users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                     users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                     users#destroy
                    root        /                                        users/:user_id/items#index
                    root        /                                        devise/sessions#new
```

And logging in and going to `localhost:3000` gets me a Routing error: `uninitialized constant Users`

I've tried changing it to

```
  authenticated :user do
    root :to =>  'items#index'
  end
```

And that gets me the error `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"items"}`

I can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out the correct route was the latter:

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to =>  'items#index'
end
```

and the error I was getting was actually from my view. I had to remove the new_user_item_path link_to from the view. I'll figure out how to link to a new item after this.

Comment: I had to pass the user to the path. `new_user_item_path(current_user)`